# Selenium IDE is not recording with mousedown event

Tags: jquery, firefox, selenium, selenium-ide

I have created a simple div and changing its background-color on mousedown and mouseup events.Then I tried testing with Selenium IDE in firefox.The issue is,  It is not recording any of the mouse actions. Here is the jsfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/62epjrLm/). Is there any suggestions to overcome this issue in Selenium IDE?

```
 $("#demo").mousedown(function () {
                    $("#demo").css('background-color', 'yellow');
                }).mouseup(function () {
                    $("#demo").css('background-color', 'blue');
                });

<div id="demo" style="width:200px;height:100px;background-color:red;"></div>
```

Selenium IDE is not working even the elements are directly added in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE will not record clicks to elements that aren't "clickable".

In Selenium IDE terms, this `<div>` is not clickable.  You will manually have to add this step.

`click | id=demo`

Source: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/ide/main/src/content/recorder-handlers.js#L159

That being said, if you needed to click on that `<div>`, you could add an empty `onclick` attribute.

```
<div id="demo" onclick style="width:200px;height:100px;background-color:red;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.How to do Selenium IDE recording with Mousedown and Mouseup events at runtime?